# How to use Data.Type.Natural's Typeable Instance

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type

Data.Type.Natural just added a `Typeable` instance, one for the promoted type `'Z` and one for `'S`. Although in practice this means that every `Nat` is `Typeable`, the compiler doesn't seem to know that. As a result, I'm having trouble making use of the instance to (for example) show a `Nat`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, DataKinds, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Natural
import Data.Typeable

import Unsafe.Coerce

data Depth a = forall n . D (Proxy (n :: Nat))

getConstraint :: forall n . Proxy n -> Dict (Typeable n)
getConstraint _ = unsafeCoerce (Dict :: Dict ())

instance Show (Depth a) where
  show (D proxy) = 
    case getConstraint proxy of
      Dict -> show $ typeRep proxy

test :: Depth a -> Depth a -> Depth a
test (D (Proxy::Proxy n1)) (D (Proxy::Proxy n2)) = D (Proxy::Proxy (Max n1 n2))

main = print $ show $ test (D (Proxy::Proxy N0)) (D (Proxy::Proxy N1))
```

This fails at runtime with the error `internal error: stg_ap_v_ret`

Richard Eisenberg said "An `unsafeCoerce Dict` can be used to satisfy any arbitrary constraint" in [this mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.glasgow.user/24445). I tried that idea here, but my solution is triggering a GHC "bug". However, when I looked on the GHC trac, I found that [GHC is allowed to get angry](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7323#comment:6) if `unsafeCoerce` is used improperly, and I suspect that's just what I've done.

Another approach is to try to get the constraint from a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, DataKinds, PolyKinds, GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Foo where

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Natural
import Data.Typeable

import Unsafe.Coerce

data Depth :: (* -> *) where
  D :: forall n a . (Typeable n) => Proxy (n :: Nat) -> Depth a

instance Show (Depth a) where
  show (D proxy) = show $ typeRep proxy

test :: Depth a -> Depth a -> Depth a
test (D (Proxy::Proxy n1)) (D (Proxy::Proxy n2)) = D (Proxy::Proxy (Max n1 n2))

main = print $ show $ test (D (Proxy::Proxy N0)) (D (Proxy::Proxy N1))
```

but `test` cannot deduce `Typeable (Max n1 n2)`, and I don't see any way to make GHC deduce that other than the `unsafeCoerce` hack attempted in the other solution.

In my actual code, I'm trying to get away with keeping `Depth` of kind `* -> *` and to have the `Nat` type existentially quantified. Any other ideas on how I could print out the `Nat` value in a `Depth`?

Comment: When Richard said that `unsafeCoerce Dict` could satisfy an arbitrary constraint, I expect he meant from the type-checker's perspective.  You're actually trying to use the dictionary though, which definitely won't work.

Comment: Hm, I was working off of [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syntactic-1.12.1/docs/src/Language-Syntactic-Constructs-Binding.html#evalBindM) example from the syntactic library. It looks like that's exactly what they did.

Comment: I don't think it's what syntactic does, because I can't find an `unsafeCoerce` in that example.  It looks like they already have a `Typeable` and are extracting just that from the full set of constraints.  But I've never looked at syntactic before, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: My understanding is that `unsafeCoerce` is at least as crazy as `accursedUnutterablePerformIO`, so code using it should be expected not to work until proven otherwise.

Comment: Since your Nat is existentially quantified, the only thing you can do with it is call functions from `Typeable` on it. So you may as well just store the `typeRep`. Since the `typeRep` gives you nothing more than just storing a value level integer, you essentially just have an integer. The only time you can unsafeCoerce a Dict "safely" is when the constraint can't introduce any values. For example, `(1 <= n + 1) ~ True` cannot produce values, while things like `Show X`, `Typeable X`, etc, can.